# strange output from phantomjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs

I have a script as follows :

```
page.open('http://google.com',function(){
    var base64 = page.renderBase64('PNG');
    system.stdout.writeLine(JSON.stringify({
        image: base64
    }));
    page.close();
    phantom.exit(0);
}
```

when I run this using `phantomjs script.js` I get the output as `{"image":"content"}`. But when I run the same using `node index.js` which spawns phantom and runs the same script I get something like 
`undefined:1
{"image":"content"}`

What could be the cause for this undesired output of undefined:1

the node.js script is as follows:
`

```
var phantomjs = require('phantomjs');
var childProcess = require('child_process');
var spillOver = '';
var phantomProcess = childProcess.spawn(phantomjs.path,['./image.js']);
phantomProcess.stdin.write(JSON.stringify({url:"http://google.com"}) + '\n');
phantomProcess.stdout.on('data', function(data){
var stringData = data.toString();
  if(stringData.indexOf('\n')===-1){
    spillOver += stringData;
  }else{
    stringData = spillOver+stringData;
    spillOver = '';
  }
  stringData.split('\n').forEach(d =>{
    if(d === '')
      return;
    var result = JSON.parse(d);
    console.log(result);
  });
  var result = JSON.parse(stringData);
  console.log(stringData);
});

phantomProcess.on('exit', function(code){
  console.log('exited with code'+code);
});
```

`

Comment: Please edit your question and include the minimal enough for reproduction node.js script. If PhantomJS script does not produce undefined output, the only logical explanation is that node script does that.

Comment: @Vaviloff I have added the node script which can reproduce the error. Please have a look. Thanks